# Partition to then restore windows 10 computer

Tags: windows, partitioning

So I want to create a partition with files that i want to keep whilst i factory restore my computer, like so the partition is untouched and i can access it once I have reinstalled my windows 10 so i don't have to re-download all of my previous software. how can i go ahead and do this.

When i try use the built in factory reset on windows 10, its all broken so I am thinking of restoring with ASUS Backtracker or a new usb.

Comment: Use a disk external, your current plan, will format your hdd.  Of course you will still have to reinstall the software so go ahead and download the software now before you format

Answer (score -1):

Can you save them to another drive and then factory reset? This is what I have done in the past and it's a bit easier than partitioning the drive.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)